# How can I predefine helm search patterns?

Tags: helm

I have some commonly used helm regexp search patterns, can I save them for quick reuse?

Maybe bind them to shortcuts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you should be able to bind a macro to any key for a specific task as long as you know the corresponding keymap. For example:

```el
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-c l") (kbd "../"))
```

Now, <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> will enter `../` during all helm sessions.

If you want to bind it only for a specific helm command, you can look at the various `helm-*-map`s available. However, not all helm commands define their own map, so you may need to resort to more extreme measures. If that's the case, a new question may be appropriate.